# Trying to find min and max from txt file with strings and floats

Tags: python, max, min

I'm trying to find the min and max values (floats) from a txt file formatted like this:

```
name
grade
name
grade
name
grade
```

When I run my code, I get a

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code, can't seem to figure out the issue.

```
def main ():
    #open gradebook
    gradebook_file = open ('gradebook.txt', 'r')

    #define name
    name = gradebook_file.readline ()

    while name != '':
        grade = float (gradebook_file.readline ())

        name = name.rstrip ('\n')

        print ('Name:', name)
        print ('Grade:', grade)

        name = gradebook_file.readline ()  

    #append numbers in gradebook
    data = []
    for lines in gradebook_file:
        data.append (grade)

    #define min and max values
    _min = min (grade)
    _max = max (grade)

    #print contents
    print ('The minimum average grade was a(n) ' + str (_min) + '.')
    print ('The maximum average grade was a(n) ' + str (_max) + '.')

    #close the gradebook
    gradebook_file.close ()

#call main
main ()
```

Comment: `grade` is a float, so I'm not sure what you expect `min` and `max` to do with a float, but as the error says, floats are not iterable. As an aside, your `for` loop, `for lines in gradebook_file` will not work because you already exhausted the file-handler. You have to either `seek` back to the beginning of the file or, better yet, use `with` blocks to open your files every time you want to iterate over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're discarding each `grade` as you read the next one, rather than storing them in a sequence for use with `min`/`max`. Thus, you're trying to compute the min and max of the last grade seen, which is nonsensical (you compute min and max of a collection of values, not a single value). You need to preserve the grades as you go, or keep a running min and max (which uses less memory, but requires more custom code you can get wrong).

If you want to store all the grades, try something like this:

```
from future_builtins import map, zip  # Required on Python 2 for lazy map/zip

def main ():
    #open gradebook using with statement, so it's closed automatically/predictable
    with open('gradebook.txt') as gradebook_file:
        data = []

        # Pair your lines up automatically with zip
        # and convert grades to floats automatically with map
        for name, grade in zip(gradebook_file, map(float, gradebook_file)):
            name = name.rstrip('\n')

            print('Name:', name)
            print('Grade:', grade)
            data.append(grade)  # Store for later

    #define min and max values
    _min = min(data)
    _max = max(data)

    #print contents
    print('The minimum average grade was a(n) {}.'.format(_min))
    print('The maximum average grade was a(n) {}.'.format(_max))

#call main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

An alternative to using `data` to store all the grades just to get two of them would be to replace:

```
data = []
```

with:

```
_min, _max = float('inf'), float('-inf')  # Initial values; will be replaced immediately
```

then keep running minimums and maximums by replacing:

```
data.append(grade)  # Store for later
```

with:

```
_min = min(_min, grade)  # Or faster but more verbose: if grade < _min: _min = grade
_max = max(_max, grade)  # Or faster but more verbose: if grade > _max: _max = grade
```

and removing:

```
_min = min(data)
_max = max(data)
```

since you no longer create or populate `data`. That approach means a truly huge set of inputs only needs to be scanned once, and not stored at all, rather than storing all the grades and scanning them twice. Performance-wise, it's unlikely to matter though, unless your inputs are so huge you might run out of memory (unlikely for a grade tracking program).